# what is the reason Planner Tasks app is not available for Microsoft Teams private and shared channels

Tags: office-365, microsoft-teams

I have a Microsoft Private Teams, which contains; 2 standard channels + 1 private channel + 1 shared channel.

now for the standard channels i can create planner plan for them, as follow:-

[image: thumbnail image 1 of blog post titled]

while for the private and shared channels this option is not available, as follow:-

[image]

so what is the reason behind this , that we can not create planner plan for private and shared channels, even if i go to the related SharePoint site for the private and for the shared channels this option is not there as well:-

[image]

Any adivce?